# Filename modification

Tags: files, rename

Lets say I have 1000 files named as  `file1.txt` ... `file1000.txt`

I need to change the file name if the number is divisible by 10.

I did this and it just change the first letter

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.doc"; done
```

Comment: Hello Mansour and welcome.  You need to do some checking if the numbers which are part of the filename can be devided by 10. An example can be the following: `for f in *.txt; do fname="${f%.*}"; n="${fname//[^[:digit:]]/}"; if (( n % 10 == 0)); then echo mv -- "$f" "foo_${fname}".doc; fi; done`   If the results look good you can remove the `echo` and run the command

Comment: If the number to be divisible by is actually 10, you can exploit the fact that divisibility by 10 is equivalent to the last digit being 0 and loop over *0.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Henrik supports the community`'s comment is apt.  Also, I am always an advocate of **printing** the commands to be executed, and then reviewing those commands closely.  This gives you a built-in "dry run" feature.  **If** the commands look correct, then run the script again and pipe the output to `sh`.  OTOH, if the commands are not correct, then no damage has been done.

```
for f in *0.txt
do
    printf 'mv -- %q %q\n' "$f" "${f%.txt}.doc"
done
```

Thanks to Stéphane Chazelas for suggesting the more secure usage of `printf`'s `%q` directive.

Comment: It's dangerous to do it that way. For instance, if you had a `$(reboot)0.txt` in the current directory, piping the output of that loop to `sh` would cause a reboot. Some `printf` implementations support `%q` to print something as shell code that represents a string which would be generally safer. So `printf 'mv -- %q %q\n' ....`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you!  My `printf` man page does not document `%q` but the implementation does support it.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use the perl `rename` utility (may be named `prename`, `perl-rename`, `file-rename` depending on what kind of unix, or linux distro you are running).

For example:

```
$ touch file{1..100}.txt
$ rename -n 'm/\w+(\d+)\.txt$/; if ($1 % 10 == 0) { s/\.txt$/.doc/ }' file*
rename(file100.txt, file100.doc)
rename(file10.txt, file10.doc)
rename(file20.txt, file20.doc)
rename(file30.txt, file30.doc)
rename(file40.txt, file40.doc)
rename(file50.txt, file50.doc)
rename(file60.txt, file60.doc)
rename(file70.txt, file70.doc)
rename(file80.txt, file80.doc)
rename(file90.txt, file90.doc)
```

This `rename` script does a regex match to capture the digits just before the `.txt` into capture group 1 (`$1`).  Then, if $1 is divisible by 10, rename the file by modifying `$_`.

Note: The `-n` option of `rename` makes this a dry-run, it only prints what would be renamed without actually renaming anything.  To actually rename the files, either remove the `-n` from the command or replace it with `-v` for verbose output.

BTW, perl `rename` can do a lot more than that.  you can use any valid perl code to rename files - if the code changes `$_` (the current filename), it will be renamed.  If it doesn't change `$_`, it won't be renamed.  It's effectively a specialised scripting language for file renaming operations. BTW, `rename` wont rename a filename over an existing file unless you force it to with the `-f` option.

e.g. if you also wanted to rename all files so that the numbers were zero-padded to 4 digits long, add `s/\d+/sprintf("%04i",$&)/e` to the rename script:

```
$ rename -v 'm/\w+(\d+)\.txt$/;
             if ($1 % 10 == 0) { s/\.txt$/.doc/ };
             s/\d+/sprintf("%04i",$&)/e' file*
file100.txt renamed as file0100.doc
file10.txt renamed as file0010.doc
file11.txt renamed as file0011.txt
file12.txt renamed as file0012.txt
...
...
...
file98.txt renamed as file0098.txt
file99.txt renamed as file0099.txt
file9.txt renamed as file0009.txt
```

All filenames are renamed to zero-padded versions, and some of them (the ones where the number is divisible by 10) are also renamed to doc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way that should work and quite save to execute.

```
for f in *.txt
  do 
    fname="${f%.*}"  # strip away the extension
    n="${fname//[^[:digit:]]/}" # keep only the digits
    if (( n % 10 == 0)); then  # use modulo to check if the remainder is 0 when n is devided
      echo mv -- "$f" "foo_${fname}".doc 
    fi
  done
```

So to understand the logic of the above, let's try an example just with numbers 1..1000

```
n=({1..1000}); for n in "${n[@]}"; do if (( n % 10 == 0 )); then echo "$n <-- can be divided by 10"; fi; done
```

Which will produce:

```
10 <-- can be divided by 10
20 <-- can be divided by 10
30 <-- can be divided by 10
....
....
```